# Using a multimeter to measure the VPP directly from an AWG output, how to?

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement, multimeter

tomorrow I'll have a lab class and we were told what we'll do in advance. So, since I don't want to be unprepared I started thinking about how to "solve" the problems, and I'm hardstuck at this one.

We have an [HP33120A](https://www.sglabs.it/public/SgLabs_HP_33120A_1.JPG) aribitrary waveform generator (AWG) and a [MOD-U1272A](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61kKmNxLB5L._SL1141_.jpg) multimeter. The problem is to have the AWG set to generate a sine waveform with given parameters, and I can do that, and then measure the VPP through the multimeter. If I can connect everything correctly* then I should be able to read on the MOD-U1272A's display the RMS of the wave, which is VP/sqrt(2), and then calculate the VPP from it.

The point is, I don't really know how to connect the multimeter to the AWG, especially, where should I connect the COM probe of the multimeter? I think I should need a common voltage reference for both the AWG and multimeter but the HP33120A doesn't have a GND connector if I saw correctly. Then how should I do it?

Thanks in advance, this managed to made me kinda nervous and it would be a great relief if I managed to find out.

Answer (score 3):

The 33120A is an arbitrary waveform generatorm, not an oscilliscope. The output connector is a BNC coax connector - the outer shell of that connector is the ground connection.

If you do have an oscilliscope, the probes should have ground leads, and the input connectors on the oscilliscope will probably also be BNC coax,with the shell of the connector being ground.

Comment: noted and corrected about the 33120A, thanks. I need to use the multimeter to measure the Vpp directly from the AWP out.

Comment: Same applies. Ground to ground, signal out to multimeter positive. Not that it really matters, if you hook it up backwards it should still be the same if it's a symmetrical ac +- across 0V type signal. Otherwise the value would be negative or skewed.

Answer (score 0):

The multimeter should be attached to the output BNC connector of the AWG. Normally, you'd use some kind of a BNC-to-banana converter, and some BNC cable.

[image]

The AWG is on the top, the multimeter is on the bottom. The multimeter can also be a handheld model, of course.